# Flume NG and HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, flume

I am very new to hadoop , so please excuse the dumb questions.

I have the following knowledge
Best usecase of Hadoop is large files thus helping in efficiency while running mapreduce tasks.

Keeping the above in mind I am somewhat confused about Flume NG.
Assume I am tailing a log file and logs are produced every second, the moment the log gets a new line it will be transferred to hdfs via Flume.

a) Does this mean that flume creates a new file on every line that is logged in the log file I am tailing or does it append to the existing hdfs file ??

b) is append allowed in hdfs in the first place??

c) if the answer to b is true ?? ie contents are appended constantly , how and when should I run my mapreduce application?

Above questions could sound very silly but a answers to the same will be highly appreciated.

PS: I have not yet set up Flume NG or hadoop as yet, just reading the articles to get an understanding and how it could add value to my company.

Answer (score 5):

Flume writes to HDFS by means of HDFS sink. When Flume starts and begins to receive events, the sink opens new file and writes events into it. At some point previously opened file should be closed, and until then data in the current block being written is not visible to other redaers.

As described in [the documentation](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#hdfs-sink), Flume HDFS sink has several file closing strategies:

- each N seconds (specified by `rollInterval` option)
- after writing N bytes (`rollSize` option)
- after writing N received events (`rollCount` option)
- after N seconds of inactivity (`idleTimeout` option)

So, to your questions:

a) Flume writes events to currently opened file until it is closed (and new file opened).

b) Append is [allowed](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-1700) in HDFS, but Flume does not use it. After file is closed, Flume does not append to it any data.

c) To hide currently opened file from mapreduce application use `inUsePrefix` option - all files with name that starts with `.` is not visible to MR jobs.