# Apache Flume creating new file for every line write

Tags: flume, flume-ng

i was doing some experiement to get feel of the flume. and below is my configuration file.

```
agent.channels.memory-channel.type = memory

agent.sources.tail-source.type = exec
agent.sources.tail-source.command = tail -F /root/test.txt
agent.sources.tail-source.channels = memory-channel

agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.channel = memory-channel
agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.type = hdfs
agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.path = hdfs://10.0.7.111/tflume
agent.sinks.hdfs-sink.hdfs.fileType = DataStream

agent.channels = memory-channel
agent.sources = tail-source
agent.sinks = hdfs-sink
```

for each line adding to the test.txt file using vi command when look at the flume log it is creating new file in HDFS /tflume directory. why so ?

I was expecting to flume to append to my existing file and at the same time, data writing to hdfs is also talking too long time by looking at the log.

appreciate for reply in advance.

Comment: This question is probably a duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17724391/flume-ng-and-hdfs. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17745182/217079

Answer (score 2):

This is the infamous 'many small HDFS files' problem while using HDFS as a sink.

The problem is easily solved by making sure at least the properties rollSize, rollCount, rollInterval and idleTimeout are set for the HDFS sink in your flume.conf. If you don't set them Flume defaults to very low values. Most of the time the default for rollSize (only 1024 kb !!) will dictate that only 3 to 4 log records are recorded in 1 HDFS file.
The defaults can be conveniently overridden by setting their values to 0, but if you forget this the defaults will make for some eractic behaviour.

```
#ALWAYS PROVIDE THESE OVERRIDES OF THE DEFAULTS !!

agent3.sinks.snk1.hdfs.rollSize = 0
agent3.sinks.snk1.hdfs.rollCount = 0
agent3.sinks.snk1.hdfs.rollInterval = 0
agent3.sinks.snk1.hdfs.idleTimeout = 0

#SET TO YOUR NEEDS

#rollCount writes to hdfs every 20 lines
agent3.sinks.snk1.hdfs.rollCount = 20
```